# Converting for-loop to lapply function on two data frames with if condition

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

How can I convert these loops to lapply function or another fast function to speed up?

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("a", "g", "h", "l", "n", "e"), 
  V2 = c("b", "n", "i", "m", "i", "f"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("a", "c", "b"), 
  V2 = c("b", "d", "a"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(df2)) {

    if (df1[i,]$V1==df2[j,]$V1 & df1[i,]$V2==df2[j,]$V2 | 
        df1[i,]$V1==df2[j,]$V2 & df1[i,]$V2==df2[j,]$V1) {

      res1 <- df1[i,]
      res2 <- df2[j,]
      res <- rbind(res1, res2)

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `df2[do.call(paste0,as.data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, sort)))) %in% do.call(paste0, df1),]`

Comment: Can you please explain with words what are you trying to achieve? It looks a bit like a join to me, but I'm not sure from the example.

Comment: @liborm I want to subscript between two data frames so I want to paste rows that are the same in two data frames and their inverse in a new data frame

Answer (score 3):

If you only have two columns, you could also use `pmin` and `pmax`. and then combine it with `merge` in order to find common rows

```
lookup <- setNames(data.frame(do.call(pmin, df2), 
                              do.call(pmax, df2), 
                              1:nrow(df2)), 
                   c(names(df2), "indx"))
df2[merge(lookup, df1)$indx, ]
#   V1 V2
# 1  a  b
# 3  b  a
```

Or using `data.table` for more efficiency

```
library(data.table)
lookup <- setnames(data.table(do.call(pmin, df2), 
                              do.call(pmax, df2)),
                   names(df2))
indx <- lookup[df1, on = names(df2), which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L]
df2[indx, ]
#   V1 V2
# 1  a  b
# 3  b  a
```

Comment: I remember I used `>` to order the dataset instead of `pmin/pmax` in the past.  Nice one.

Comment: @David Arenburg I don't know why when I used your ode in my data set in lookup line it makes new column named indx that includes numbers , but in the example it wouldn't do that?!!

Comment: It is creating a new column called `indx` in the `lookup` data set in order to subset the `df2` data set accordingly. I don't understand what you mean by "*but in the example it wouldn't do that?!!*"

Comment: In the example It creates lookup variable same as df2 with two column as df2 but in my own data set it creates lookup variable with three columns , first two columns are as columns in df2 but third column is indx column and contains numbers

Comment: Now I tried your second solution and occured error after indx line: "Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io, xo, roll, rollends, nomatch,  : 
  x.'V1' is a character column being joined to i.'NA' which is type 'NULL'. Character columns must join to factor or character columns.e: "

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about really. The lookup table creates an ordered version of `df2` and adds an `indx` column. Regarding your error, it works fine on your example data set. If you don't like this solution, use the akruns solution instead.

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
df2[do.call(paste0,
      as.data.frame(t(apply(df2, 1, sort)))) %in% 
         do.call(paste0, df1),]
#  V1 V2
#1  a  b
#3  b  a
```